# Prevent my C code from printing (seriously slows down the execution)

Tags: c, ubuntu, printing, solver

I have an issue.

I finally found a way to use an external library to solve my numerical systems. This library automatically prints the matrices. It is fine for dim=5, but for dim=1.000.000, you understand the problem...

Those parasite "printf"s slow down considerably the execution, and I would like to get rid of them. The problem is: **I don't know where they are !** I looked in every ".h" and ".c" file in my library: they are nowhere to be found.

I suspect they already are included in the library itself: `superlu.so`. I can't access them, thus.
[image: libsuperlu]

**How could I possibly prevent my C code from printing anything during the execution ?**

Here is my Makefile. I use the [libsuperlu-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libsuperlu-dev/filelist) library, directly downloaded from Ubuntu. The .so file was already there.

```
LIB = libsuperlu.so

main: superlu.o read_file.o main.o sample_arrays.o super_csr.o
    cc $^ -o $@ $(LIB)

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm main
```

Comment: a bit hacky, but you could redirect all output to /dev/null.

Comment: I do not think that would prevent the overhead of printing the text, it would simply appear as if nothing had been printed

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` and remove the calls to `printf` so they don't print. OR modify the binary and remove all calls to it. Patch it out. OR build it yourself? https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu

Comment: @WillisHershey, redirecting the output to `/dev/null` won't avoid *all* the overhead of printing, but it typically does avoid a significant fraction of that overhead.  Output to an interactive device is often *especially* slow.

Comment: I think the solution OP is looking for is a way to ask the linker to link a null function in the place of `printf()` and/or `puts()`, which is not something I know how to do off the top of my head, but it seems like it should be possible

Comment: @WillisHershey Try it. Write a program that calls `printf("hello, world\n")` one million times, and then calls `fprintf(stderr, "bye\n")` one time. Run it with and without redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: A take-away from this experience: Never do this to people. If you want a library that's truly reusable, don't make these sorts of decisions. Dump the results into a big-ass array or whatever, definitely, but let the caller decide how, when, or if it is printed. Side note: *I have an issue.* is noise. The fact that you have a problem is implied by asking a question here

Comment: Anyway, the first step is usually to consult the documentation, not to trawl the code.  If a computational library is really the source of unwanted diagnostic messages then I would fully expect there to be a way to turn them off programmatically, rather than by modifying the library source or playing dynamic linker games or even using I/O redirection.

Comment: Alternatively, it may be that you have [built] a debug version of the library that intentionally emits messages not intended for normal library builds.  In this case, I would expect there to be build options by which these messages could be eliminated.  For this, too, the first step would be to check the docs.

Comment: @user3386109 I did, and you're right (more right than I was expecting), but linking a function defined as `int print(const char *f, ...){ (void)f; return 0;}` was still faster than the `/dev/null` redirect by a factor of about 2. I simply don't know how to avoid linkage via the `stdio.h` namespace collision.

Comment: The most time spend by printf, when printing on a terminal, is really in the interaction with the device. Even the fastest terminal emulator is very slow, compared to code spent in printf itself. So, redirecting to `/dev/null` would really spare most of the time.

Comment: @WillisHershey It's technically **undefined behavior** to replace any of the standard library functions, including `printf`. So even if it seems to work, you shouldn't be doing that. Personally, I agree with John Bollinger that the OP's first step should be to consult the documentation.

Comment: If you're talking about it printing the solver statistics, there's the `PrintStat` boolean member on the `superlu_options_t` struct. Have you tried setting that to false?

Comment: When building the library, try `-D PRNTlevel=0` and do not define `DEBUG`. According to the source code I linked in an earlier comment, it will not print if this is the case. The library only uses `printf` to log and `fprintf` if an error occurs. It will only use `printf` if `DEBUG` is defined and `PRNTlevel >= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to explain the `LD_PRELOAD` method that was mentioned, that I use sometimes precisely for that usage (or, on the contrary to add some printf, for example, when I want to pipe the output of a GUI), here is how you can do a rudimentary version of it

myprint.c:

```c
int printf(char *, ...){
    return 0;
}

int putchar(int){
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
gcc -shared -std=gnu99 -o myprint.so myprint.c
```

Then

```
LD_PRELOAD=./myprint.so ./main
```

Forces the load of your `printf` and `putchar` symbols before any other library has the opportunity to load them force. So, no printing occurs. At least none with printf. But you may have to add some other functions to the list, such as `fprintf`, `fputc`, `fputs`, `puts`, ...

And of course, another problem of overloading the `fthing` functions (and even possibly the others), is that you might also prevent some wanted behavior. Such as writing files. Or interacting with some devices.

It may be even worse if those printing are done with low level `write` function. That one, you very likely can't afford to overload (unless you overload it with a function that calls the real `write`, loaded manually by `dlopen`) filtering only the ones that you want to avoid, based on target file descriptor (1) or on content of written data.

Note: if you want to verify if the `libsuperlu.so` is responsible of those printing, you can check with `nm libsuperlu.so` if it is referring to some well known printing functions, such as `printf`

Comment: The library very likely has a way to turn these off, which is probably a lot easier

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I first tried to look at `libsuperlu.so` with the `nm` command, but my terminal says: `nm: libsuperlu.so: no symbols`. When I try to access it with `nano libsuperlu.so`, I get `�^C^Eȫ��^_��4��^O^W^` symbols... An idea to make `nm` work ?

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg : Yes. Use `nm -D` instead (I should have said so from the start. Symbols of dynamic library are read with `nm -D`. Those are the symbols that are used for dynamic linking. Just, libraries that have not been stripped have also the classical ELF symbols, so I am used to have `nm` working most of the time, without the `-D`)

Comment: Thanks to `nm -D` I have been able to localise the `printf`s. For instance, I see: `U __fprintf_chk` under a line `0000000000009b90 T TreePostorder`. Unfortunately, `nm` doesn't let me mody the script, only read. Would you know how to do it ? Could I rewrite the entier `.so` file from a text file for instance ?

Comment: I have asked another question here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74557925/19930448. Meanwhile, I'll mark your answer as accepted.