# Modify a .so file using Linux terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .so, nano

I need to solve the following problem to (finally !) finish my numerical analysis project:

I need to modify a `.so` library to delete some unwelcome `printf`s (see [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74524890/19930448)). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74525245/19930448) I got taught me how to read the `.so` file from my Ubuntu terminal (WSL-2 under Windows 10) with the instruction `nm -D library.so`:

```
.../CodePub2.1/Superlu$ nm -D libsuperlu.so 
0000000000007170 T DenseSize
0000000000006880 T Destroy_CompCol_Matrix
0000000000006960 T Destroy_CompCol_Permuted
00000000000068c0 T Destroy_CompRow_Matrix
...
```

I would like to delete all lines with `printf`s, e.g. :

```
0000000000009b90 T TreePostorder
                 ...
                 U __fprintf_chk
```

The `nm` instruction only let me read the file. When I try the `nano` instruction, I get unreadable characters, like `�^C^Eȫ��^_��4��^O^W^`.

I put the library in an [accessible Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w8tYggT3mjec8dZhspbwqHqjVvylqtWJ/view?usp=sharing) if you need it. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Modifying a binary is _much_ more complex than you imagine. The proper fix is to get the source and recompile it with the changes you want. A quick and dirty fix is to replace the output calls with no-ops in the binary, but you need several days or probably weeks of learning to understand how computers actually work to pull that off.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer on the other question if it's not suitable for your needs (and/or you didn't understand it at all)?

Comment: @tripleee I haven't tried the "hard way" proposed by the answer yet and I was hoping for a more easy way. I accepted the answer for the efforts provided and because their probably won't be another answer. That said, I have doubts now

Comment: `nm` is not showing any code, and cannot help to edit anything. The `printf` you see in its output are not some calls to printf. Even if you could just "remove those lines" (which doesn't make sense), it would not remove calls to printf. It would just make the linking fail. Those `printf` in this `nm` output are just, somehow, references. Indication that the library use `printf` (since it requires that this function is present to be used). So, linker will have to provide `printf` symbol before running the program. It that requirement is not met, the program will simply not run.

Comment: My answer (which, indeed, I was not advising. It was replying to "how to do so", but wasn't saying that it is a good idea to do so. In fact, in comments to your question, I even confirm that those who where advising an output redirection with a simple `> /dev/null` where right), my answer explains how to provide a "fake" `printf` symbol to the linker, so that it doesn't use the one in `libc`. So, your code (main code as well as libraries) would call my `printf` rather than the default one.

Comment: And the reason why I pointed to `nm` was not to provide an easier way as an alternative to that really hard way. It was to tell how to identify which "fake" functions you need to write. Because, there are more than one way to print things in C. `printf`, `fprintf`, `putchar`, `fputs`, `write`, are only a few of them. So you need to identify which are those you need to `deactivate` with fake functions. And one first hint, is to list the symbols that `libsuperlu` references. For example in the extract you provide we can see that it calls `fprintf`. So, that one may need to be "faked".

Comment: But again, that is the hard way. Because `fprintf` is also used to write files. And I suppose you need the library to do something with its result. Or even for more "internal" usage, such as filling some memory. So you don't necessary want to disable all `fprintf` calls. If you are to use this road, you need to load the real `fprintf` symbol, and call it back from your fake `fprintf`. But tracing in the meantime the call. So that you can analyze the usage, and find a criteria to decide which calls you need to disable and which one you need to keep.

Comment: It is not impossible. I found myself doing exactly that once or twice in my life (for the exact opposite reason: because a closed source program was not verbose enough for me. So I hijacked its calls to some `write` calls, but not all of them, to add some printing for some of them). It works. But that can be almost qualified as "hacking". And it took me a whole day, knowing exactly what I was doing (I mean, I knew how to use `LD_PRELOAD`, `dlopen` etc.) to finally find the correct criteria for my "hijacking".

Comment: Going back to your initial question, I would reiterate what was said in comments there: first thing is to identify how badly you need to remove those printtf. How much of them there are (expressed in, say, characters per second)? It is true that heavy printing can slow down code. But, that is (depending on the terminal) when it is really heavy. A few dozen thousand characters per second should not slow it sensibly. And secondly, as suggested in comments, why not just redirect output?

Comment: Contrarily to what was said by one commenter (and contradicted by many), most of the time spend in `printf` and likes are not in the internal code of those (formatting, filling buffers, etc.) but in the interaction with the terminal. And that time is annihilated if you redirect to `/dev/null`

Comment: ok, thanks. I don't need this specific code to print anything actually, but another one needs to. Maybe is it wiser for me to try another library instead of trying to provent the code from printing, if it is that hard ?